# $\int_E f\;d\mu=0\implies f=0$ a.e. in $E$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space and let $f$ be a non-negative measurable function defined on $X$. It is known that $$\boxed{\int_X f\;d\mu=0\implies f=0\quad\text{a.e in}\; X.}$$

Now, let $E\in\mathcal{A}$ be any measurable set and we suppose that $$\int_E f\;d\mu=0.$$ Then we have that $$\int_E f\;d\mu=\int_X f\chi_E\;d\mu=0,$$ then for the previous result we have that $$f\chi_E=0\quad\text{a.e in}\; X$$

**Question.** From this can I conclude that $f=0$ a.e. in $E$?

Comment: yes you can :-)

Comment: @SurbCan you explain me the motivation?

Comment: What is the definition of "a.e"? @NatMath. I think it should be useful.

Comment: What do you know about where $f\chi_E$ can be non-zero?

Comment: The argument of "$\int_E f=0$ implies $f=0$ a.e. $x\in E$" is simply the duplicate of the counterpart in which $E$ is replaced by $X$ : $\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ , $m\{x\in E\ :\ f(x)>\frac{1}{n}\}=0$, and hence $$\{x\in E\ : f(x)>0\}=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_+} \{x\in E\ : f(x)>\frac{1}{n}\}$$ is of measure $0$.

Comment: And your method is also a good one. It suffices to show that "$f\chi_E=0$ a.e. $x\in X$ implies $f=0$ a.e. $x\in E$". For $x\in E$ , $f(x)\chi_E(x)=f(x)$, hence for $x\in E$, $f(x)\ne 0$ $\iff$ $f(x)\chi_E(x)\ne 0$, i.e. $\{x\in E\ : \ f(x)\ne 0\ \}=\{x\in E\ :\ f(x)\chi_E(x)\ \ne 0\ \}$. The set of the right hand side is of measure $0$, since it is the subset of $\{x\in X\ :\ f(x)\chi_E(x)\ \ne 0\ \}$, which is of measure zero by hypothesis.